# compare two revisions of the same file

Tags: git, aptana

In eclipse 4.2, with aptana plugin 3.2.

I've seen several answers regarding a comparison between the current file and another revision, but I'm looking for a way to compare two previous revisions of the same file.

So Right Click > Compare with > Revision... does not work as I can only choose one revision.

The Resource History window doesn't help either.

What I would like to do is to choose two different commit in a 'commit tree' relative to the file, then compare them.

Comment: Willing to use the command line diff, or must this be in eclipse only?

Comment: Well it's an aptana related question, so yes, I want to to this in eclipse.

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so it would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped or provide your own so other people could benefit from the knowledge, thanks!

Comment: The problem is not solved, aptana|git has not this feature. So, there's a "unsolvable" status to put on this question!

Answer (score 1):

if talking about GUI only then checkout project to revision abc456, compare the file with revision dfg786 ?

if command line is fine:

git diff abc456 dfg786 -- filename

Comment: Is this the only solution? In EGit we can compare two revisions in the history tree. This feature seems to be missing.

Comment: Are you talking about the ability to select two commits in history view and compare them using right click "compare to Each Other"? I suspect that if this approach is not available for you in aptana plugin than my solution will be the only one.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about that. The only solution in eclipse is to use egit instead of aptana|git

Comment: it seems that at this point Egit is so advanced that it doesn't make much sense to use anything else from within eclipse